# Kotlin zipAll alternative

Tags: scala, kotlin

Does Kotlin have a function like `.zipAll` in Scala?

In Scala I can sum two array with different length using the [zipAll](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.6/scala/collection/View$$ZipAll.html) function.

Scala:

```
val arrA = Array(1,2,3)
val arrB = Array(4, 5)
arrA.zipAll(arrB, 0, 0).map(x => x._1 + x._2)
```

Or what is the correct way to do this in Kotlin?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no in-build analog in Kotlin 1.0. It might be a good idea to add it into the stdlib. Feel free to file an issue on the YouTrack

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I filed issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-13017.

Answer (score 2):

Here is `zipAll` for Kotlin:

```
fun <T1: Any, T2: Any> List<T1>.zipAll(other: List<T2>, emptyValue: T1, otherEmptyValue: T2): List<Pair<T1, T2>> {
    val i1 = this.iterator()
    val i2 = other.iterator()
    return generateSequence {
        if (i1.hasNext() || i2.hasNext()) {
            Pair(if (i1.hasNext()) i1.next() else emptyValue,
                    if (i2.hasNext()) i2.next() else otherEmptyValue)
        } else {
            null
        }
    }.toList()
}
```

And a unit test:

```
@Test fun sumTwoUnevenLists() {
    val x = listOf(1,2,3,4,5)
    val y = listOf(10,20,30)

    assertEquals(listOf(11,22,33,4,5), x.zipAll(y, 0, 0).map { it.first + it.second })
}
```

And the same could be applied to arrays, other collection types, sequences, etc.  An array-only version would be easier since you can index into the arrays.  The array version could be:

```
fun <T1: Any, T2: Any> Array<T1>.zipAll(other: Array<T2>, emptyValue: T1, otherEmptyValue: T2): List<Pair<T1, T2>> {
    val largest = this.size.coerceAtLeast(other.size)
    val result = arrayListOf<Pair<T1, T2>>()
    (0..this.size.coerceAtLeast(other.size)-1).forEach { i ->
        result.add(Pair(if (i < this.size) this[i] else emptyValue, if (i < other.size) other[i] else otherEmptyValue))
    }
    return result.filterNotNull()
}
```

It returns a `List` because `map` function is going to turn you into a list anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I made a quick tail-recursive version for fun. Not very efficient though, due to the list appends.

```
fun <T, U> List<T>.zipAll(that: List<U>, elem1: T, elem2: U): List<Pair<T, U>> {
    tailrec fun helper(first: List<T>, second: List<U>, acc: List<Pair<T, U>>): List<Pair<T, U>> {
        return when {
            first.isEmpty() && second.isEmpty() -> acc
            first.isEmpty() -> helper(first, second.drop(1), acc + listOf(elem1 to second.first()))
            second.isEmpty() -> helper(first.drop(1), second, acc + listOf(first.first() to elem2))
            else -> helper(first.drop(1), second.drop(1), acc + listOf(first.first() to second.first()))
        }
    }

    return helper(this, that, emptyList())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This does not yet exist in the Koltin stdlib, but this is the suggested approach I posted in  the [youtrack ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-13017) about this.

---

Here is a potential implementation modeled after the current `zip` function https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/zip.html.

```
/**
 * Returns a list of values built from the elements of `this` collection and the [other] collection with the same 
 * index using the provided [transform] function applied to each pair of elements. The returned list has length of 
 * the longest collection.
 */
fun <T, R, V> Iterable<T>.zipAll(
    other: Iterable<R>,
    thisDefault: T,
    otherDefault: R,
    transform: (a: T, b: R) -> V,
): List<V> {
    val first = iterator()
    val second = other.iterator()
    val list = ArrayList<V>(maxOf(collectionSizeOrDefault(10),
        other.collectionSizeOrDefault(10)))
    while (first.hasNext() || second.hasNext()) {
        val thisValue = if (first.hasNext()) first.next() else thisDefault
        val otherValue =
            if (second.hasNext()) second.next() else otherDefault
        list.add(transform(thisValue, otherValue))
    }
    return list
}

// Copying this from kotlin.collections where it is an Internal function
fun <T> Iterable<T>.collectionSizeOrDefault(default: Int): Int =
    if (this is Collection<*>) this.size else default
```

And here is how I use it

```
/**
 * Takes two multiline stings and combines them into a two column view.
 */
fun renderSideBySide(
    leftColumn: String,
    rightColumn: String,
    divider: String = " | ",
): String {
    val leftColumnWidth: Int = leftColumn.lines().map { it.length }.maxOrNull() ?: 0

    return leftColumn.lines()
        .zipAll(rightColumn.lines(), "", "") { left, right ->
            left.padEnd(leftColumnWidth) + divider + right
        }
        .reduce { acc, nextLine -> acc + "\n" + nextLine }
}
```

---

Example of how I am using this:

```
val left = """
    Left Column
    with some data
""".trimIndent()

val right = """
    Right Column
    also with some data
    but not the same length
    of data as the left colum. 
""".trimIndent()
```

`println(left)`

```
Left Column
with some data
```

`println(right)`

```
Right Column
also with some data
but not the same length
of data as the left colum.
```

`println(renderSideBySide(left,right))`

```
Left Column    | Right Column
with some data | also with some data
               | but not the same length
               | of data as the left colum.
```

`println(renderSideBySide(right,left))`

```
Right Column                | Left Column
also with some data         | with some data
but not the same length     | 
of data as the left colum.  |
```

Comment: Cool! Thanks a lot! )